# System.InvalidCastException (A cannot cast B, but A and B are the same)

Tags: c#, .net-6.0

By sending the user's number to an API I have, I get information about the user. After that, I add this information to the cache, and when I need this information at another time, I want to pull it out of the cache and use it.

But when I want to use this structure, I get an error like the following, I have also examined similar questions. In general, the assembly is shown at different addresses. But I am getting this error even though they are both at the same address.

What could be the reason for this situation and how can I find a solution?

> *System.InvalidCastException:
> '[A]Assistant.Models.BtcApi.UserService.UserResponseBody cannot be
> cast to [B]Assistant.Models.BtcApi.UserService.UserResponseBody.
>
> Type A originates from 'Assistant, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=null' in the context 'Default' at location
> 'C:\Projects\Btc\bin\Debug\net6.0\Assistant.dll'.
>
> Type B originates
> from 'Assistant, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=null' in the context 'Default' at location
> 'C:\Projects\Btc\bin\Debug\net6.0\Assistant.dll'.'*

```
  public UserResponseBody GetUserByPhoneNumber(string phoneNumber)
    {
        if (phoneNumber.StartsWith('+'))
            phoneNumber = phoneNumber[2..];
        else if (phoneNumber.StartsWith("9"))
            phoneNumber = phoneNumber[1..];
        string cacheId = phoneNumber + userCache;
        if (CacheManager.Exists(cacheId))
        {
            var users= GetUserByCatch(cacheId);
            return users;
        }
        var client = GetClient();
        var request = new RestRequest($"/api/Login", DataFormat.Json);
        request.AddJsonBody(new
        {
            phoneNumber,
        });
        var responseBody = client.PostAsync<UserResponseBody>(request).Result;
        AddCacheUser(responseBody, cacheId);            
        return responseBody;
    }
    public UserResponseBody GetUserByCatch(string cacheId)
    {
        var res = (UserResponseBody)CacheManager.Get<object>(cacheId);
        return res;
    }
    public void AddCacheUser(UserResponseBody user,string cacheId)
    {
        CacheManager.Add(cacheId, user, TimeSpan.FromHours(1));
    }
```

Additional My Program.cs

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddDbContext<DataContext>();
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();
builder.Services.AddHttpClient();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary<string, ConversationReference>>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IBotFrameworkHttpAdapter, BotFrameworkHttpAdapter>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IBot, TeamsBot>();

var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}

app.UseDefaultFiles()
    .UseStaticFiles()
    .UseWebSockets()
    .UseRouting()
    .UseAuthorization()
    .UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });

app.Run();
```

Comment: try a clean build

Comment: also don't use `.Result`. make your code async

Comment: Try clean and rebuild. If it does not help - delete bin and obj folders manually (optionally - restart IDE) and rebuild again.

Comment: Are you loading that assembly dynamically? Loading it twice perhaps? Or using a direct reference in the main project but loading it dynamically from *another* one? Is the error thrown at `(UserResponseBody)CacheManager.Get<object>(cacheId);`? Why is that cast used instead of `Get<UserResponseBody>` ?

Comment: You're not using a "shared project" are you?

Comment: I've tried clean and build before, I even deleted the bin and obj folders, it didn't help.

Comment: (UserResponseBody)CacheManager.Get<object>(cacheId); actually it was in the structure you said at first, but it stayed in that state while we were trying different things to see if there was an error due to the cast process.  I dynamically load this build directly from my own project.

Comment: What do you mean by shared project?

Comment: If you don't know then I guess you're not using one. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/managing-references-in-a-project?view=vs-2022#shared-project-references

Comment: I use different projects as layered architecture, they were directly included in the project in the past, but now I pull them all as nuget.

Comment: Seems like a baffling problem. You might consider [fusion logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/fuslogvw-exe-assembly-binding-log-viewer#to-log-all-assembly-binds) to see which DLLs are getting loaded exactly.

Comment: Do you have a [mre] at hand? Can you post one?

Answer (score 0):

The project in my hand is fed from the nugets prepared by our company, so I override some methods and make transactions. When I add cache data during these operations, I have trouble pulling the data in this cache from the main menu (I can only pull it as an object, I can't convert it to another type).

For this reason, I developed a solution as follows using 2 caches, although I don't like this solution, it solves my problem for now.

I'm waiting for your different suggestions, thanks in advance for your help.

```
public UserResponseBody GetUserByPhoneNumber(string phoneNumber)
        {
            if (phoneNumber.StartsWith('+'))
                phoneNumber = phoneNumber[2..];
            else if (phoneNumber.StartsWith("9"))
                phoneNumber = phoneNumber[1..];
            string cacheId = phoneNumber + userCache;
            if (CacheManager.Exists(cacheId))
            {
                var users = GetUserByCatch(cacheId);
                if (users is null)
                {
                    cacheId += "1";
                    if (CacheManager.Exists(cacheId))
                        return GetUserByCatch(cacheId);
                }
                else
                    return users;
            }
            var client = GetClient();
            var request = new RestRequest($"/api/Login", DataFormat.Json);
            request.AddJsonBody(new
            {
                phoneNumber,
            });
            var response = client.Post(request);
            var responseBody = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserResponseBody>(response.Content);
            AddCacheUser(responseBody, cacheId);
            return responseBody;
        }

        private UserResponseBody GetUserByCatch(string cacheId) =>
                     CacheManager.Get<UserResponseBody>(cacheId);

        private void AddCacheUser(UserResponseBody user, string cacheId) =>
            CacheManager.Add(cacheId, user as object, TimeSpan.FromHours(1));
```